# .hgignore and xmldoc

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial

I want to ignore the xmldoc file for the Visual Studio project in Mercurial.
My .hgignore below

```
syntax: glob
*.xml
```

Fail

```
syntax: glob
[Assembly name].xml
```

Fail

Help Me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) provides a good [example](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html#example):

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

*.elc
*.pyc
*~

# switch to regexp syntax.
syntax: regexp
^\.pc/
```

In your case, this should be fine:

```
# use glob syntax.
syntax: glob

*.xml
```

Make sure you have the path to the relevant file(s) correct with respect to the location of your .hgignore file.

Comment: I see official documentation and therefore do not understand what the problem :(

Comment: Now save empty .hgignore and list files no changed, i.e. must be also files from bin and obj subdirectories :(

Comment: I solved the problem deleting the local copy of the project, and repairing it from the repository:)